# Trying to map an Array to an Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular and reactive forms and have a permissions object for access to items on page. Basically I'm trying to map the returned API array of objects to a formgroup set of formgroups. I'm not interested in formarray as I've got a lot depending on the structure that's in the database.

But, having the hardest time trying to map this.

---

INITIAL STRUCTURE

```
[
{module_name: "users", access: true, edit: true, delete: false},
{module_name: "documents", access: true, edit: false, delete: false}
]
```

ANGULAR FORMS DESIRED STRUCTURE

```
accessControl: {
users: {access: true, edit: true, delete: false}
documents: {access: true, edit: false, delete: false}
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code where you try to map the structure and we point you what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce);

```js
const input = [{
    module_name: "users",
    access: true,
    edit: true,
    delete: false
  },
  {
    module_name: "documents",
    access: true,
    edit: false,
    delete: false
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { module_name, ...rest } = curr;
  acc[module_name] = rest;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr.forEach(module => {
   accessControl[module.module_name] = {
     access: module.access, edit: module.edit, delete: module.delete
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Yair Cohen answer, but without specify parameters passed from data:

```js
var accessControl = {};

var data = [
    { module_name: "users", access: true, edit: true, delete: false },
    { module_name: "documents", access: true, edit: false, delete: false }
];

data.forEach(x => {
    accessControl[x.module_name] = x;
    delete accessControl[x.module_name].module_name;
});
console.log({ accessControl });
```

Comment: Also good. In fact I'm not sure about the parameters on the way in, it's not codified yet, so it can expand. Thanks